# How to select item in asp.net listbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using followig jquery script to add dates in asp.net listbox and it works fine, but i want to select a last added item as well and unselect the others. I have tried using

```
$("#lstVisitDates option[value='" + svc + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

but it is selecting all items in the listbox.

jQuery script

```
function AddDate() {
var txt = $("span[id$=spVisitDates] input[type=text]"); 
var svc = $(txt).val()   
var lst = $('#lstVisitDates');
var options = $('#lstVisitDates option'); 
var alreadyExist = false;
$(options).each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == svc) {
        alert("Item alread exists");
        alreadyExist = true;
        return;
    }
});
if (!alreadyExist)
    $(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '">' + svc + '</option>');
    $("#lstVisitDates option[value='" + svc + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
return false;
```

}

Comment: Why not set selected at the time of appending? `$(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '" selected="selected">' + svc + '</option>');`

Comment: i think i need unselect all items first then add a new item with select option otherwise it selects all items.

Comment: unselect all items first $(lst).find("option").attr("selected", false); and then add a new value and select it $(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '" selected="selected">' + svc + '</option>');

Comment: i have updated my question. sorry

Comment: For unselecting the items in dropdown you need to loop through each options.

Comment: If you want to select last added item then one line of code is enough, Try this after appending options  `$("#lstVisitDates option:last").attr("selected","selected")`

Comment: would it unselect the others?

Comment: For unselect you need to loop through all options first!

Comment: this works for me, unselect all items first $(lst).find("option").attr("selected", false); and then add a new value and select it $(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '" selected="selected">' + svc + '</option>');

Comment: See my answer below, you'll get better idea

Answer (score 0):

Try to set value directly using val() as follow:This is even more simple

```
if (!alreadyExist)
    $(lst).append('<option value="' + svc + '">' + svc + '</option>');
    $("#lstVisitDates").val(svc);
return false; 

}
```

**See Demo:**

**JS fiddle** : **[Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkfzx/3/)**